# Como puedo enviar un dato almacenado en sessionStorage a php

Tags: php, javascript

He probado varias formas de enviar datos almacenados en un sessionStorage pero ninguno me ha funcionado.
probé con esto:

```
<script>
sessionStorage.setItem('data', 'my data');
var data = sessionStorage.getItem('data');
</script>

<?php
$phpdata = "<script>document.write(data)</script>";
echo $phpdata;
?>
```

pero no funciona.

No sé qué més probar, por favor ¿me pueden ayudar?

Que sea un código sencillo y que no necesite cargar otra página, que haga todo el proceso en la misma página.

Comment: Lo puedes hacer utilizando AJAX.

Comment: Cómo puedo usarlo?

Comment: Tal vez [esto](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49829738/10053314) te pueda ayudar

Comment: ¿Por qué usas php para esta prueba? Podrías lograr lo mismo haciendo document.write(data) dentro del primer bloque <script>

Comment: Aquí el problema es que estás confundiendo los momentos de la ejecución de tus scripts. JavaScript se ejecuta en el cliente, PHP en el servidor. Es lo que dice @VickMuñoz. Necesitas usar Ajax. Puedes ver ejemplos en https://academy.leewayweb.com/un-dashboard-en-tiempo-real-basado-en-php-y-bootstrap/ y https://academy.leewayweb.com/como-hacer-un-autocomplete-con-php/

Comment: ¿En qué momento quieres pasar el dato? ¿Ya probaste usar cookies?

Comment: uso php porque necesito un id que me proporciona una tabla y debo pasarlo a php para obtener un dato almacenado en mysql pero no necesito cambios de pagina, si no hacer el proceso en la misma